# Wget data from a script

Tags: curl, screen-scraping, wget

Here's an example website:

http://www.indianyellowpages.com/business-services/advertising/

When you click any of the 'View Contact Details' buttons (and register, no e-mail confirmation needed), a small window pops up. How would I download data from this window using wget (or curl)?

EDIT: Or perl.

Comment: You can not do that with only curl or wget, because those programs does not understands javascript, but you can implement that using your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Sure, use Mechanize for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with either wget or curl. or Perl.

The correct procedure would first involve you recording a "manual" session to figure out exactly what requests your browser sends to achieve what it's doing. Then you convert that into the proper wget or curl command line or perl script. Or whatever.